# Find and create folders with EAGetMail on Exchange

Tags: c#

I have a Main class that retrieve email account information

```
static void Main()
{
    MailServer oServer = new MailServer(serverName, emailAccount, password, ServerProtocol.ExchangeEWS);
    oServer.SSLConnection = true; oServer.Port = 993;
    string storagePath = "inbox/folder1/folder2/folder3";
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting server ..."); 
    MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");
    oClient.Connect(oServer);
    CreateExchangeStorageFolders(oClient, storagePath);
    Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
}
```

The objective is to create the folders and subfolders as in the storagePath string. For this I implemented the CreateExchangeStorageFolders method:

```
private static void CreateExchangeStorageFolders(MailClient oClient, string storagePath)
{
    var itpath = storagePath.Split('/');
    var count = 1;
    var results = itpath.Select(x => string.Join("/", itpath.Take(count++))).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < itpath.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (FindFolder(results[i+1], oClient.Imap4Folders) == null)
        {
            Imap4Folder folder = oClient.CreateFolder(
                FindFolder(results[i], oClient.Imap4Folders),
                itpath[i+1]
            );
        }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("This folder already exists: " + itpath[i]);
    }
}
```

I implemented a FindFolder that takes in consideration the full path. In that case, there's no particular need to check subfolders.

```
public static Imap4Folder FindFolder(string folderPath, Imap4Folder[] folders)
{
    // pour chaque dossier dans exchange
    foreach (var folder in folders)
    {
        if (String.Compare(folder.FullPath, folderPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return folder;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

this code create the first folder on the right place in inbox folder. The others are created at root level.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider that i want to have such folders organization:

```
Inbox/folderA/FolderB/FolderC/...
```

I updated the code this way :

```
private static void CreateExchangeStorageFolders(MailClient oClient, string storagePath)
{
        
    var itpaths = storagePath.Split('/');
    var results = itpaths.Select(x => string.Join("\\", itpaths.Take(count++))).ToList();

    for (var i = 1; i < itpaths.Length; i++)
    {
        Imap4Folder root = Utils.FindFolder(results[i-1], oClient.Imap4Folders);
        Imap4Folder child = Utils.FindFolder(results[i], oClient.Imap4Folders);
          
        if (root == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Root folder doesn't exist");
            oClient.CreateFolder(null, results[i-1]);
        } 
        else if (child == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child folder doesn't exist");
            Console.WriteLine("root: " + root.Name);
            oClient.CreateFolder(root, itpaths[i]);
        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Nothing to do");
           Console.WriteLine("root: " + root.Name);
           Console.WriteLine("child: " + child.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

and the FindFolder:

```
public static Imap4Folder FindFolder(string folderPath, Imap4Folder[] folders) 
{ 
    // pour chaque dossier dans exchange
    int count = folders.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Imap4Folder folder = folders[i];
        if (String.Compare(folder.LocalPath, folderPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
           return folder;
        }

        folder = FindFolder(folderPath, folder.SubFolders);
        if (folder != null)
        {
            return folder;
        }
    }

    // No folder found
    return null;
}
```